# How to find a spider when there is a spider web?

Tags: pest-control, bedroom

I have an aircraft model in my bedroom and saw a spider web attached to the wing today. I want to find the spider. How would I best do this?

Comment: @Revulai I don't know. Probably pretty small though.

Comment: Don't, it's much better to have a spider than a few, or a few dozen, other insects. (Note to biologists: yes, i know spiders aren't insects). If you never have insects anyway, your spider won't stay (alive) very long either.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If the web is still inhabited by a spider, you could try to gently blow on the web. This will cause it to start vibrating, making the spider believe a bug is caught in it. It will come out of its hiding place (on one of the corners of the web) to sting the bug. This is when you can kill/catch it.

Comment: Wow okay I guess I will try that.

Comment: Well spiders don't have a sting, but the rest of the comment should work.

The spider has likely moved on anyway if you have nothing for it to eat (i.e. insects around).